# Find the critical value in Tukey's HSD

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I'm trying to find the formula for finding the critical values for [Tukey's HSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test#The_studentized_range_.28q.29_distribution) but I can't find any documentation on how to calculate the critical value based on the number of groups the type I error probability and the within group degrees of freedom so basically [this](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring98/sta110c/qtable.html) table. Could someone explain this?

Comment: As I recall, this is a somewhat messy integration problem, usually done by numerical integration. Hence the use of tables to make computation unnecessary. Also, you could get very close by simulation. The distribution is sometimes called the 'studentized range' distribution. References in the Wikipedia article on that topic may be useful.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I know a formula to calculate the CDF for infinite degrees of freedom, or if k (number of groups) is two,